# remove non numerical and strange character from string

Tags: bash

I have this temperature

-4.7�C

I want to get only the number with - and . I use

```
 sed 's/[^-.0-9]*//g'
```

But � doesn't disappear, what should I do to delete it?

Comment: you need to escape the period with \

Comment: That is a character encoding problem. A better solution is to find out which character encoding was used to create the original file and open the file using that encoding. Then you should get a degree symbol rather than the "unknown" symbol.

Comment: @BrianMcCall, a dot is not special inside a character class

Comment: you've almost certainly got a degree symbol there but in the wrong code-page, if you can figure out which code page (try ISo-8859-13 and CP850 in that order) you can use `iconv` to convert it. `iconv -f 8859-13 -t utf-8`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo '-4.7�C' | tr -cd '0-9.-'
```

Output:

```
-4.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure BASH solution based on glob:

```
s='-4.7�C'
r="${s//[^-.[:digit:]]/}"

echo "$r"
-4.7
```

Comment: at the end of a chain like the folloving, how do you insert your solution? awk 'NR == 3' Temperature.txt | cut -d '>' -f 5 | cut -d '<' -f1

Comment: All 3 command I.e. awk, cut and this conversion can be combined into single awk command. Just let me know what you're trying to do here?

Comment: If you show a small sample of your input file `Temperature.txt` then I can help you with a single awk command to do all that.

Answer (score 0):

this will erase it

```
tr -d $'\200'-$'\377' | sed ...
```